# ReplaceNoCase multiple times for a single string

Tags: coldfusion

I have a string that changes based on who is viewing it. What I am trying to do is find keywords and change what they say based on that.

To solve this problem I am trying to use `ReplaceNoCase` multiple times on the string but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(fullresults.question, '##clientbrand##', customTags.clientbrandname,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(fullresults.question, '##LocationName##', customTags.locationName,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(fullresults.question, '##LocationGroup##', customTags.DoctorGroupName,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(fullresults.question, '##ServiceProvider##', customTags.specialist,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(fullresults.question, '##SalesContact##', customTags.salesperson,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(fullresults.question, '##Product_Procedure##', customTags.procedurename,"ALL")>
```

When my string contains #clientBrand# in it with the above code it just displays '#clientBrand#' and when I am only trying ReplaceNoCase once, it displays the correct outcome.

Do I have any issues with my code? Is there another way to replace multiple variables?

Comment: I found my mistake. Mods please close.

Comment: Have you considered using a `replacelist()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that I was resetting `ques` to the original form every time I was doing the replacenocase

```
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(fullresults.question, '##clientbrand##', customTags.clientbrandname,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(ques , '##LocationName##', customTags.locationName,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(ques , '##LocationGroup##', customTags.DoctorGroupName,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(ques , '##ServiceProvider##', customTags.specialist,"ALL")>
<cfset ques = Replacenocase(ques , '##SalesContact##', customTags.salesperson,"ALL")>
 <cfset ques = Replacenocase(ques , '##Product_Procedure##', customTags.procedurename,"ALL")>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Some additional work may be needed of commas appear in any of the after strings

```
<cfset before="##clientbrand##,##LocationName##,##LocationGroup##,##ServiceProvider##,##SalesContact##,##Product_Procedure##">

<cfset after = "#customTags.clientbrandname#,#customTags.locationName#,#customTags.DoctorGroupName#,#customTags.specialist#,#customTags.specialist#,#customTags.salesperson#,#customTags.procedurename#">

<cfset ques = ReplaceList(fullresults.question, before, after)>
```

Comment: I could try that. Thanks!